# Wordpress Leave A Comment error

Tags: wordpress

After inspecting my clients website i have noticed that one of the fields of the comment form is incorrect.  The field has a label that says `Name2` instead of `Name`.
[image]

As you can see in the image above, the field says `Name2(required)`.  How can i change this so it simply says `Name`.  The theme they are using is purchased(Shoptan), i've checked the plugins none of them affect the comment form, how do i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I would recomment using a full text search on the plugin and theme directories for the text "Name2" to find the cause of the problem.

If you find the file and place this string is included in, we can probably help you to find the solution very quickly.